# How to fix a Footer to the bottom of a page after a while loop in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, while-loop, footer

Below is a PHP file with some HTML. I am trying to fix the footer to the bottom of the page, after the while loop executes and flows the products from left to right.

The problem is that when the DOM changes, so does the flow of products and it starts to overlap the footer or there is space after the products.

Can anyone shed some light on this topic? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    DEFINE ("DB_USER", "root");
    DEFINE ("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    DEFINE ("DB_PASSWORD", "myroot");
    DEFINE ("DB_NAME", "corporate");
    
    $dbc = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    
    mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
    
    $q = "SELECT sku, name, price FROM products";
    
    $r = $dbc->query($q, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
    
    echo "<div class='wrapper'>";
    echo "<header>header</header>";
    
    while(list($sku, $name, $price) = $r->fetch_row())
    
    printf("<div class='item'>(%s) <br>%s:<br>\$%d</div>", $sku, $name, $price);
    echo "<footer>footer</footer>";
    echo "</div>";
    ?>
```

**HTML**

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title></title>
**CSS**
<style>
                    body{
                        margin: 0;
                    }
                    *, *:before, *:after{
                        box-sizing: border-box;
                    }
                    header{
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 200px;
                        background:  blue;
                        padding: 100px;
                        color:  white;
                    }
                    div.wrapper{
                        width: 100%;
                        height:  auto;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
            div.item{
                display: flex;
                width: 200px;
                height: 300px;
                background:  blue;
                color:  white;
                float: left;
                margin: 10px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                border:  1px solid gold;
                justify-content: center;
                padding-top: 120px;
            }
            div.item:hover{
                display: flex;
                font-family:  helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:  700;
                width: 200px;
                height: 300px;
                background:  darkblue;
                color:  gold;
                float: left;
                margin: 10px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                border:  1px solid gold;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            footer{
                display: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                height: 200px;
                color:  white;
                background:  blue;
                margin-top: 960px;
                padding: 100px;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your .footer class replace: `margin-top: 960px;` with `clear: left`